# Expected 1 arguments, but got 0, LocalStorage

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I'm stuck with local Storage 2days

I have no idea how to solve this problems,

I tried save input values to local Storage, but it's something very wrong going..

I thought this is very simple resolve, but not to me

atom.tsx

```
import { atom, selector } from "recoil";
import { getLocalStorage } from "./util/localstorage";

export interface ITodo {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}

export interface IToDoState {
  [key: string]: ITodo[];
}

export const toDoState = atom<IToDoState>({
  key: "toDos",
  default: getLocalStorage() ?? {
    "To Do": [],
    Doing: [],
    Done: [],
  },
});
```

localStorage.tsx

```
import { IToDoState, toDoState } from "../atoms";

export const setLocalStorage = (toDos: IToDoState) => {
  return localStorage.setItem("toDos", JSON.stringify({ toDos }));
};

export const getLocalStorage = (toDos: string) => {
  const localToDos = localStorage.getItem(toDos);
  if (localToDos) {
    return JSON.parse(localToDos);
  }
};
```

Board.tsx

```
function Board({ toDos, boardId }: IBoardProps) {
  const setToDos = useSetRecoilState(toDoState);
  const { register, setValue, handleSubmit } = useForm<IForm>();
  const onValid = ({ toDo }: IForm) => {
    const newToDo = {
      id: Date.now(),
      text: toDo,
    };

    setToDos((allBoards) => {
      console.log(allBoards);
      return {
        ...allBoards,
        [boardId]: [...allBoards[boardId], newToDo],
      };
    });

    setValue("toDo", "");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage({ toDos });
  }, [{ ...setToDos }]);
```

Comment: Well, it sure *seems* like it's complaining because `getLocalStorage` is written to accept 1 argument and you're calling it with 0 arguments, but we can't be sure unless you post the actual error.

Comment: Thanks to comment ! There was no error, but toDo list not saved correctly, No error and code is something wrong. I'm reading every details of code and googling but do not know what to exactly ask :(